# Avoid writing logs in multiple files at same time - log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm having problem with log4j loggin. I've a aplication that writes lots of logs thats why when it crosses the limit of the file size it generates new file. My `log4j.properties` files is given below.
If I put MaxBackupIndex unlimited then there is no problem. But if I put a limitation and the backup index reach this limit then the logging system became mad. It starts writing to different log files at same time which makes impossible to track the log files.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,R,C

#Appender R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/file_location/app.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p]%d{DATE} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=30720KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10

#Appender C
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.C.Threshold=error
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p]%d{DATE} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.C.File=/file_location/apps_err.log
```

For example:

```
I've app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2 ..... app.log.9. When It reaches the limit than it starts writing something like the following order:
app.log.7
app.log.2
app.log.9
etc etc....
```

It doesn't follow any rules to write in the files. Now temporarily what i did is increased the limit of BackupIndex.

Anyone have any idea how to get rid of this annoying logging. There are lots of issue about how to make multiple log files but i didn't find how to avoid this type of multiple writtings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your config says: When the logfile `app.log` reaches the size of `MaxFileSize=30720KB` then split the logfile and keep a history of ten files `MaxBackupIndex=10`. Or I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: You are right. All log files splitted when it reaches 30mb and it keeps 10 files. 
But the problem is when all the 10 files is full and need to write more logs. I prefer to delete the old one and start writing again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `RollingFileAppender` and your Configuration says that whenever the Log Size reaches ~30MB `(MaxFileSize=30720KB)` then split the log file. The other option `(MaxBackupIndex=10)` will keep the history of 10 files at most.

Also, the Logger Instance is Async and thus the logs printed will not be in sync.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me what can I use on the place of RollingFileAppender?
what I want is to remove the oldest file and keep writing the log in a file that I can control.

Comment: You can use FileAppender. It will write to one file only.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But FileAppender don't do what I want to do. FileAppender write everything in a single file. I can't put size limit or File limit for rolling files.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The settings do what you specify.

take following example settings (which reduces the log files size for demonstration purpose to `1KB`)

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=app.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p]%d{DATE} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

using this snippet

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
class LoggerTest {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("logger");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 129;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append('x');
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
            logger.info(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

will produce the following files

```
app.log    
app.log.1  
app.log.2  
app.log.3  
app.log.4  
app.log.5  
app.log.6  
app.log.7  
app.log.8  
app.log.9  
app.log.10
```

As soon the logifle `app.log` will be bigger then the `MaxFileSize` it is renamed to `app.log.1`. An existing `app.log.1` is renamed before to `app.log.2` and so on till the maximum number of `MaxBackupIndex` is reached then the olderst file is deleted.

If your goal is to have only a single logfile `app.log` with a maximum size of `MaxFileSize` you might set `MaxBackupIndex` to zero. But his has one side effect. If `app.log` reaches the `MaxFileSize` it is dropped and the following logging statements will go into a new **empty** file.

Amend the above properties to `log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=0` the size of `app.log` will be

```
0
200
400
600
800
1000
0
200
400
600
800
1000
...
```

There is no built-in solution to keep a single logfile which not grows over the `MaxFileSize`. As this would mean as soon `MaxFileSize` is reached you need to delete the oldest logging entries from the beginning of the file.

One possible solution might be to set `MaxBackupIndex` to one. So you would end up only with `app.log` and `app.log.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explication...
My goal is to has (for ex) 10 backup files as you mentioned app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2 ..... app.log.10 and when 10 backup files created with max file size then remove the oldest file and keep writing in the app.log file.  No problem is, when it reaches the limit then it starts over writing randomly in different files.

Comment: I don't want a big single file because it'll become difficult to read or open the file in any text editor.

Comment: @NadimAseqAArman `MaxFileSize` is for the main logging file (in this case `app.log`) not for the total size of all logfiles `app.log + app.log.1 + ...`. Do you mean if a new file `app.log` is created because it had reached the limit of `MaxFileSize` then you still get entries into one of the backups e.g. into `app.log.1`? Then you should give an example to demonstrate how it looks like. How do you access the logger in your code?

Comment: No no! i understand that. 
when app.log reaches maxsize then it rename the file app.log.1 and starts again app.log. This buckle continues till MaxBackupIndex. Till now I don't have problem.
But when all the backup index created and the current app.log reaches it's size limit then I want to delete the oldest file and keep writing app.log.
The problem I'm facing is, it starts writing on more than one file randomly.
Temoporary solution is, MaxBackupIndex unlimited or a higher number can avoid this random writing.

Comment: @NadimAseqAArman If in the example you change the value to `MaxBackupIndex=5` you will have backups only till `app.log.5` (instead of getting them till `app.log.10`). Each time `app.log` will be renamed to `app.log.1` the `app.log.5` will be deleted and `app.log.4` is renamed to `app.log.5` (as it is specified in `MaxBackupIndex`). As mentioned before: Please add an example. It's really unclear what's your problem.

Comment: exactly... what you said.... I assume according to my code it should do what you said. if MaxBackupIndex=5 then it should delete app.log.5 and rename app.log.4 to app.log.5. But in my case, it's not deleting any file. It's removing lines of a backup file and writing on it. For example: it's randomly writing few lines of new log to app.log.3, few lines on app.log.5 and few lines on app.log ... 
I don't have example because all the old files has been cleared by the server admin.

Comment: @NadimAseqAArman Ok now. This sounds for me not as a configuration problem. When a single application is writing to `app.log` using `log4j` with those settings I cannot imagine a case where this might happen (using log4j). Following might be a reason: the log4j logging is used in an uncommon way, another application is also writing to `app.log` not using `log4j`, different applications use log4j with the same configuration. For the last point I'm not sure if this really would lead into problems.

Comment: yes there is another application using log4j with same configuration but not writing to same files. They are using different files to log.

Comment: @NadimAseqAArman Then you should analyse the code how log4j is used. Based on the log entries (which are inserted in the wrong files) you should be able to identify the related code places.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `RollingFileAppender` use `DailyRollingFileAppender`. `DailyRollingFileAppender` per day it writes 2 log files only (AM and PM). Maybe this will resolve your problem. If you want any other details let me know.. will explain

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).